# Вызов C# метода с C++ кода

Tags: c#, c++, .net, clr

Мне нужно вызвать с# метод в нейтив с++. Я нашел [пример](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/695387/Calling-Csharp-NET-methods-from-unmanaged-C-Cplusp), пример рабочий, но там старая версия плюсов/.net, и не смог воспроизвести. Работает примерно вот так:

C# .dll -> C++/CLI(managed c++) -> c++

C#

```
public static class ManagedClass
    {
        public static bool Check()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Managed c++

```
namespace ClassLibrary1 {

    public ref class DoWork
    {
    public: bool CheckCSharp()
    {
        return CSharp::ManagedClass::Check();
    }
    };
}
__declspec(dllexport) bool Check()
{
    ClassLibrary1::DoWork work;
    return work.CheckCSharp();
}
```

c++

```
#include "ClassLibrary1.h"
_declspec(dllexport) bool Check();

int main()
{
    std::cout << Check();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Ошибки

> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl Check(void)"
>   (?Check@@YA_NXZ) referenced in function _main
>
> 1 unresolved externals

Comment: Если ф-ция Check у вас реализована в cli - то первое - не експорт - а импорт. А второе - нужно создать или def или lib файл, с ссылкой на библиотеку где ф-ция реализована, и подключить в с++ проэкт.

Comment: Если у вас студия читайте http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp (может отличатся от того что я ниписал выше) Если нет - ищите "c++ dynamic linking dll"

Comment: Если лень мучатся с линкером и опциями среды  - есть простой подход. LoadLibrary + GetProcAddress. 100% сработает но менее красиво. Что б было красиво - прийдется изучить динамическое связывание в с++.

Comment: В с++ `_declspec(dllexport) bool Check();` - не верно, потому что тут вы импортируете, а не експортируете.

Comment: @nick_n_a Самое интересноее то, что я повторил в тупую пример, в сорсах примера работает, у меня нет в линкере у них других либ нет.

Comment: @nick_n_a Кстати, даже если в примере убрать `_declspec(dllexport) bool Check();` и заменить на `bool Check();`, все равно работает

Comment: Т.к у вас всё единый sollution - думаю что студия связала автоматически. То что import не потребовался - это особенности работы линкера. Моё первое предложение - это "общий случай". При динамическом связвывании есть очень много особенностей, поэтому я не готов написать ответ.

Comment: Если вы собираете все это в один исполняемый файл, а не библиотеку, то выкиньте все `__declspec(dllexport)` они не нужны.

Comment: При экспорте должно быть `_declspec(dllexport)`, а при импорте (на стороне C++) `_declspec(dllimport)`